# Cannot wipe iPad

Tags: ipad, apple-id, password

I have an iPad with another user still logged into iCloud with their Apple ID. That person has left the company and cannot remember her Apple ID password. She has tried resetting her Apple ID password but we do not have access to her emails.

Therefore we cannot wipe the iPad. What can we do?

Comment: Was the former employee unable to reset her AppleID password?

Answer (score 1):

If your company is an educational institution, and you have proof that the iPad is owned by this institution, you need to call Apple Education to have them unlock it. This has happened several times where I work, and Apple has always been able to do this for us. Seeing that we're required to purchase directly through Apple, serial numbers of our Apple devices are already in their records.

I'd call Apple Support in any case to find out the steps you need to take, but providing *proof of ownership* is essential.